# Prove that Euclidean norm is absolute symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Definiton 1: A function $f$ is called absolute symmetric if $f(Qx) = f(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and any signed permutation matrix $Q$.

Definiton 2: A signed permutation matrix is a square matrix where each column and each row has exactly one non-zero entry.

Problem: Prove that Euclidean norm is absolute symmetric, that means
$$\Vert Qx \Vert_2 = \Vert x \Vert_2.$$

Since $Q$ is signed permutation matrix I feel that $\Vert Qx\Vert_2$ is always $\sqrt{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2}$ but I can't show it in a feasible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $Q$ is a signed permutation matrix, there exists $\sigma \in S_n$ such that $Qe_j = e_{\sigma(j)}$ for all $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$. With this, your method of proof will work.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you a lot.